# Class function prototype does not match definition - how to fix

Tags: c++

This prototype does not match the definition.  How do i fix it?  I threw a const on b.c. I thought that might do it.  But not go

I know it needs the template designator in the definition even though it does not use the template...because this was a previous error.

```
// Prototype

template <class T> class dynamic_array
  {
  public:
    void print_operator(ostream)const;
  };

// Definition

template <class T> void dynamic_array<T>::print_operator(ostream &os=cout)const
  {
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) os << array[i] << endl;
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your default argument is in the implementation, it should be in the prototype
2. The implementation takes a reference, the prototype needs to take a reference too

Comment: The default value for the argument can be in either the declaration or the definition (but not both).

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I should dispute that. If I say `foo()` and the declaration says `foo(int, int, int)`, how can the TU know which arguments to insert??

Comment: @KerrekSB: I was surprised at first with it, but you can provide default values for some parameters in the declaration and for some others in the definition. You can only skip the arguments for which the compiler has a default value in the current TU. So for example you could provide a single default value in your `foo` and then users anywhere could call `foo(1,2)` and have the third one defaulted. Then provide extra values in the definition and code that sees that definition could use `foo()`. As you say the caller cannot inject default values that it does not know about.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: very interesting! But I take it that within one TU, only *one* function declaration/definition may take default arguments? If I put two in to the same file (e.g. one in the declaration at the top, and another in the implementation at the bottom), I get an error saying "default argument given after previous specification...".

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I had a hunch when I wrote it that it wasn't strictly true if the default was still available to the compiler at the point of instantiation. But will the compiler still allow it if you specify the default within the TU but after the point of use?

Comment: @KerrekSB That's almost true. You can't have two specifications for the default value of one parameter that are **in the same scope**, even if they give the same value. see § 8.3.6.(4) of the 2011 standard.


`void f(int a, int b) { cout << a << " " << b << endl; } void g() { void f(int, int = 7); f(2); } int main(int, char**) { void f(int, int = 5); f(1); g(); }` prints `1 5 2 7`

Comment: @je4d: Wow, I didn't realize you can redeclare functions inside a local scope -- nice!

Comment: I was considering a different case: `int f( int a, int b = 10 ); const int x = f( 5 ); int f( int a = 10, int ) { return a+b; }; const int y = f();` will set `x` to 15 and `y` to 20. If the header contains only the first declaration, then users that include the header must pass at least one `int`, while after the definition in the .cpp TU you can pass none. Then again, I was mistaken and this **does not apply here**, as the standard explicitly states that this cannot be done with template functions or member functions of template classes.

Answer (score 2):

You have `ostream` in one place and `ostream&` in the other. You should have `ostream&` in both places:

```
template <class T> class dynamic_array
{
public:
  void print_operator(ostream&)const;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using a reference so replace `print_operator()` with:

```
void print_operator(ostream&)const;
```

Oh and `size` and `array` must be declared elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration takes an `ostream` but your definition uses `ostream&`.